# classification using iterative thresholding in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

i'm trying to design unsupervised classifier
using the iterative threshold algorithm for lung tissue along with chest 
and i'm trying to classify pixels into chest and lung classes and i don't know what's wrong with the code

```
 x=imread("Ground_Truth_CT_001.bmp");
c=imread("CT_001.bmp");
y1=double(c(:,:,1));
lung_musk=nonzeros(y1.*double(x==255));
chest_musk=nonzeros(y1.*double(x==78));

 mean_b=mean(lung_musk)
mean_b =  53.177
 mean_n=mean(chest_musk)
mean_n =  166.03
t=(mean_b+mean_n)/2
t =  109.60              %approximately 110
Th=110;
   th0=0.5;
   Tnew=130;
     while ((Tnew - Th) < th0 )
      G1 = y1 > Th;
      G2 = y1 <= Th;

  mean1 = mean(y1(G1))
  mean2 = mean(y1(G2))
  Tnew=(1/2) * (mean1 +mean2)
  endwhile
```

Comment: It's very hard for us to help you if we don't know what results (or errors) you're currently getting, what inputs you're using, and what results you hope to achieve. Please read how to proved a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo above. I meant "provide", not "proved".